# ListView displays incorrect images for each item

Tags: vb.net, image, listview

I have a listview that lists all items from a directory like so:

[image: card gallery]

But as you can see in this image:

[image: file system]

They are not in order, because one image text has been skipped entirely, however the image itself is still in order.

But, when it gets further down the list, starting from about half way they start becoming completely mixed up like in this example:

[Image 3](http://puu.sh/ofJxH/c0a80e190c.jpg)

When clicking an image it shows the preview of the correct image on the right side.

[image 4](http://puu.sh/ofJK0/7df0bbb19b.jpg)

This is the code I'm using to load in all the images:

```
Dim imgList As New ImageList
    Dim imgSize As New Size
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim imgFilename As String

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        'Dim imlTemp As New ImageList
        Dim dirFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.GalleryLocation)

        'Dim item As New ListViewItem
        For Each dirFile As String In dirFiles
            imgFileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(dirFile)
            Dim img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(dirFile)
            Dim imgImage As Image = Image.FromFile(dirFile)
            'Dim imgHeight As Integer
            'imgHeight = imgImage.Height
            imgSize.Width = 120
            imgSize.Height = 174
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 / ((dirFiles.Count + 1) - count), img)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ListView1.SmallImageList = imgList
        ListView1.LargeImageList = imgList
        imgList.ImageSize = imgSize
        imgList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit

        ListView1.Items.Add(imgFilename, count)
        imgList.Images.Add(e.UserState.Clone)
        count += 1
        'ListView1.EnsureVisible(ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
    End Sub
```

Before I added in the backgroundworker it had tremendous loading times for a large amount of images, so I thought I'd implement the backgroundworker to allow async work to be done. However, something is going completely wrong at the start of the task and multiple times part way through the list, where it completely messes up as shown in Image 3.

Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong, or any alternative solutions to what I'm aiming to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ReportProgress()` is not blocking (as far as I know), there is a chance that the files are iterated though faster than the UI can update.

To keep this synchronized you should make a custom class holding everything you want to update and pass that to the `ReportProgress()` method (even making some steps automated).

For example:

```
Public Class GalleryImage
    Public Property FullPath As String
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property [Image] As Image


    Public Sub New(ByVal File As String)
        Me.Image = Image.FromFile(File) 'Get the image.
        Me.FullPath = File 'Save the full path of the image.
        Me.FileName = Path.GetFileName(File) 'Get the file name.
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Also, if you want the file name but not the extension you can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`)

---

Now to your code. First of all the `counter` variable isn't really necessary as it can be replaced by either `ListView1.Items.Count` or `imgList.Images.Count`.

Secondly, you shouldn't constantly keep setting the `imgSize` variable nor the ListView's `Small-`/`LargeImageList` properties. Doing that is completely unnecessary and will slow things down. For the ListView just set the image list once, and for the `imgSize` variable you can do like this:

```
Dim ReadOnly imgSize As New Size(120, 174)
```

Making the variable `ReadOnly` does what it sounds like; you can read from it, but not modify it.

Now to fix these other things we'll start in the BackgroundWorker's `For Each` loop:

```
For Each dirFile As String In dirFiles
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) 'You don't need this Sleep if you don't want to.

    'Report the progress, declare an in-line version of our class and send it with.
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 / ((dirFiles.Count + 1) - ListView1.Items.Count), New GalleryImage(dirFile)) 'A new GalleryImage is created. The property setting is handled by the class itself.
Next
```

As you see we have now narrowed the code down rather much.

Now we are going to handle the `ReportProgess()` event:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim img As GalleryImage = e.UserState 'Retrieve our class, no need to clone it.

    imgList.Images.Add(img.Image) 'Add the image first (I don't know for sure, but if you add the image after, wouldn't it require to redraw the ListView an extra time?).
    ListView1.Items.Add(img.FileName, imgList.Images.Count - 1) 'Add the new item with the values from our class.
End Sub
```

---

And lastly, the initialization and initial setting of stuff should be done in for example the `Form Load` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'In here we do all the standard settings and initializations.
    ListView1.SmallImageList = imgList
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imgList
    imgList.ImageSize = imgSize
    imgList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
End Sub
```

And by that I think I should have covered it all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you for this detailed answer, and for helping me clear up some silly mistakes...

I do have one final question though: If I wanted to refresh/reload the list would I just have to clear the list and then run the backgroundworker again?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity I swapped these 2 lines around: 

`imgList.Images.Add(img.Image) 
 ListView1.Items.Add(img.FileName, imgList.Images.Count - 1) 
`

And it was doing the same error as at the very start, so maybe this was the issue all along?

Comment: @DominikH : Yes, you can just clear the `ListView` and the `imgList` and then you can re-run the BGW.

Comment: If you're going to swap the lines you have to change `imgList.Images.Count - 1` to: `imgList.Images.Count`, but as I said **I think** doing so causes unnecessary redrawing.

Comment: @DominikH : You must clear the `imgList` too, forgot to say that.

Comment: I see, but yes, as you said, it seems better to have it in this order around, and alright - thanks for letting me know!